# avoid writing cascading if-then-else

Tags: python

Is there a way to simply my code below to not use a bunch of if-then-else?

```
if isinstance(t, int): v = 10
elif isinstance(t, bool): v = 20
elif isinstance(t, string): v = 30
...
```

Comment: `{int: 10, bool: 20, str: 30}[type(t)]`.

Comment: Those solutions will not work for derived types.  They are equivalent to `type(t) == x`, not `isinstance(t, x)`.

Comment: wow.  Does that work?  (ha.)  I would have thought you would have to use some Class names or such.  That is clever.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, that's true, it remains to be seen whether that meets the OP's needs anyway.

Comment: Dealing with derived types is exactly the reason why I didn't use dictionary mapping in the first case.

Comment: In what context does the value of `v` depend on the type of `t` in the first place? This is somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @chepner this is part of a code analyzer.

Comment: @JRR So you tried to achieve a `switch` statement but it has allready an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: Everyone suggesting the standard switch-statement idioms: consider how you would deal with `t` whose type is a subclass of a given type.

Comment: BTW, the code you have in the question will never set `v = 20`, because `bool` is a subclass of `int`: `isinstance(True, int)` is itself `True`, so `v` is set to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` that maps your types to your values, like this:

```
TYPE_TO_VALUE = {
  "int": 10,
  "bool": 20,
  "string": 30
}
```

and then assign your value like this `v = TYPE_TO_VALUE[type(t).__name__]`

Comment: This doesn't handle subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with list comprehension (this way you will cover the case for `bool`).

```py
map_={int: 10, bool: 20, str: 30}
type_map=lambda x: [map_.get(el) for el in map_.keys() if isinstance(x, el)]
t=4
print(type_map(t))
# [10]
t=True
print(type_map(t))
# [10, 20]
t="txt"
print(type_map(t))
# [30]
t=5.3
print(type_map(t))
# []
```

Alternatively to cut it down to the relevant part (IMO):

```py
map_={bool: 20, int: 10, str: 30} # notice order change
type_map=lambda x: ([map_.get(el) for el in map_.keys() if isinstance(x, el)]+[None])[0]
t=4
print(type_map(t))
# 10
t=True
print(type_map(t))
# 20
t="txt"
print(type_map(t))
# 30
t=6.7
print(type_map(t))
# None
```

Comment: This doesn't handle subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to do arithmetic with the boolean `isinstance` result.

```
def map_instance( t ):
    return isinstance( t, int ) * 10 + 
           isinstance( t , bool ) * 10 +  # bool returns 20 as it's int and bool.
           isinstance( t, str ) * 30  )
```

I think this can handle subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

two alternatives, I would choose first one (the function)

```
def get_v(my_object):
    my_types = {bool:20, int:10, str:30}
    for my_type, value in my_types.items():
        if isinstance(my_object, my_type): # first seen wins
            return value

class Spam(str):
    pass

s = Spam()
v = get_v(s)
print(v)


# ugly alternative
my_types = {'bool':20, 'int':10, 'str':30}
print(my_types.get(s.__class__.__bases__[0].__name__)) # in multiple inheritance it will take first one
```

If the dict is order-preserving (e.g. 3.7+) and bool is before int, first seen wins

Comment: It would be possible to use the loop to accumulate the calculation. i.e. `result += isinstance( my_object, my_type) * value`.  but I certainly prefer the loop

Comment: @TlsChris, the problem with the approach to accumulate is (i) if you have multiple inheritance and (ii) it doesn't break out of the loop early, but calculate for all dict elements